# Remap Glade3 button click to C Function in python

Tags: c, python-2.7, gtk3, glade

I have my python application which loads interfaces from Glade files and `connect_signals` to a dynamically loaded `Handler()` class which of course contains functions for each `signal` as defined in the glade file. What I now find myself with is that instead of defining a python function in my `Handler()` I need to execute a C function through some sort of remapping within the Handler file. If you could point me in the direction of a tutorial to compile C into a library and import it into the Handler that could work but I'm sure someone out there has a great solution i have thus far overlooked.

And it must run on Debian Linux preferably without extra packages but cross platform support is not required

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to call out to an existing C library?

You can do this directly from Python via the [ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: No I'm taking an existing C Gtk application and creating a new UI in Glade and Python and I'm exploring the possibility of using the existing C instead of a complete rewrite to Python for the backend

Comment: Ideally what you would do is make use of gobject-introspection to automatically generate Python bindings from your C code. Here is a random example of a Python application calling a C GObject library stored in-tree: https://github.com/TingPing/gnome-gpu-info.